# Performing a Parent then Child sort in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

The intention is to sort the list by the parent, and then the child (there will only be one child).

```
Example Set:
ID  ParentId Type   Unit
1   NULL    Energy  kJ
2   1       Cal
3   NULL    Protein g
4   NULL    Fat, total  g
5   4       Saturated   g
6   NULL    Carbohydrate    g
7   6       Sugars  g
8   NULL    Dietary fibre   g
10  NULL    Sodium  mg
11  NULL    Potassium   mg
```

So for example, if I sort by Type (alphabetical order) it would come up

1. Carbohydrate
2. Sugars (parent = 1.)
3. Dietary fibre
4. Energy
5. Cal (parent = 4.)
6. Fat, total
7. Saturated (parent = 6.)

Comment: when you say by parent and then by child, do you mean the IDs?  Or do you mean you want to see P1, C1, P2, C2, P3, C3, etc...?  It's a good question, it's just unclear exactly what results you'd like to see.  Perhaps a sample showing the results you'd expect?

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare Added expected set in

Comment: I would assume from your data you are guaranteed that a child id is never greater than its parent id?

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare Yes, currently, but it may not always be this way.

Comment: @iMortalitySX i don't think it's that simple.  The OP in effect wanting to join the list on itself

Comment: [Multiple Order By LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq)

Comment: [Self Join Query LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026970/linq-self-join-query-how-to-accomplish-this)

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare Indeed, you are probably correct.  I am just adding links to similar issues because I believed that is what danrhul was looking for.  danrhul, can you add what you expect the query to look like, maybe even in a SQL context?  That would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
return myData.Select(x => new { key = (x.Parent ?? x).Type, item = x})
             .OrderBy(x => x.key)
             .ThenBy(x => x.item.Parent != null)
             .Select(x => x.item);
```

Comment: This works. Just for future users: it should be `.ThenBy(x => x.item.Parent == null)`

Comment: Oops. Edited.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Ah yeah, this actually doesn't work, it just seemed to because my data was already in the right order.

Comment: Orders by the Id column it seems. I added another element to the table you see above, who's parentId was 1. But it came up last.

Comment: Hmm.  Try putting a .ToList() after the .ThenBy()?  Force it to evaluate the sort before altering what we're selecting.

Comment: This ordered to all children and then all parents

Comment: @danrhul - I just got a chance to actually try it.  I just needed to invert the ThenBy().  Try the current version.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done in two steps. First - building parent-child hierarchy (and sorting it):

```
var query = from parent in data
            where parent.ParentId == null
            orderby parent.Type
            join child in data on parent.ID equals child.ParentId into g
            select new { Parent = parent, Children = g };
```

Second - flattering hierarchy

```
var result = query.Flatten(x => x.Parent, x => x.Children);
```

For flattering I used extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Flatten<T, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<T> sequence, 
    Func<T, TResult> parentSelector,
    Func<T, IEnumerable<TResult>> childrenSelector)
{
    foreach (var element in sequence)
    {
        yield return parentSelector(element);

        foreach (var child in childrenSelector(element))
            yield return child;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var query = from p in context.Table
            from c in context.Table.Where(x => p.ID == x.ParentId)
                                   .DefaultIfEmpty()
            let hasNoParent = c == null
            orderby hasNoParent ? p.Type : c.Type, hasNoParent ? 0 : 1
            select hasNoParent ? p.Type : c.Type;
```

Comment: Apparently `c` does not exist in the current context

Comment: @danrhul - Sorry, it should have been x.ParentId

Comment: Didn't work I'm afraid, 6 nulls, followed by random repeating data

Comment: I had but hadn't noticed the change of `p : c` Even still, it just duplicates a couple of records and then just displays them in alphabetical order.